# AzureML - Trained clustering Model cannot be connected with Web Service Output

Tags: azure, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, azure-machine-learning-service

In AzureML it is not possible to connect trained Clustering Model with web service output.

Why does AzureML only allow ILearnerDotNet to be connected with Web Service Output and not IClusterDotNet?

This is a serious bug which halts clustering models from deploying them as a web service.

Comment: Azure is pretty much useless for clustering... also, you can't 'deploy' most clusterers - by design. Clustering is *explorative*, not predictive.